# Replace url component/conten/.... to MyMenu/MyCategory/

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

i have a joomla web site with 4 menu item , one of them is education that are for learnig and there have some articles.

for my template design: in 3 other menu,i disabled the `#contents`.and just in `education` menu  users can see `#contents`.

for example when a user open `education` menu he/she can choice a article and read that.that articles in `education` have a link like this : `http://www.fotografy.ir/education/2-uncategorised/20-11`.
but when a user search this article , in search contents this article have different url like this:`http://www.fotografy.ir/component/content/article/2-uncategorised/20-11?Itemid=101`.

and this article will load at component/content... where i disabled `#contents` 
and i do not want to load in there.
how can i fix this?

Comment: Please, can you add in your question the tag of Joomla's version ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use .htaccess In joomla with apache rewrite feature.

1. Rename the file htaccess.txt to .htaccess In root joomla folder;
2. Enable Apache rewrite In global configuration In joomla admin area.

Also you can try one more thing :

Goto `backend -> Menus -> Add new menu item ->` Here you can create the one menuitem with title and alias that alias name display in url. (or)

Try like this Goto `backend -> System -> Global configuration -> Turn on the sef url`.

I hope it will help you :)